# How can I implement a function that increments file names when receiving them?

Tags: python, filenames, increment

How can I write a function that makes an increment name with the incoming files?

```
def callback(ch,method, properties, body):

    Payload = body.decode("utf-8")
    Payload = ast.literal_eval(Payload)

    with open("received.png", "wb") as f:
        f.write(Payload)

    print(type(Payload))
    print("Data Received : {}".format(Payload))
```

Here I receive an image.png and name it received.png. I want to write a function that automatically renames the next incoming image something like received_2.png

Comment: Create a global variable and increment it everytime function call.

Comment: @Epsi95 "use a global variable" is the wrong answer 99% of the time

Comment: You receive bytes of an image and you use `literal_eval` ? Why so ?

Comment: @DeepSpace why? Can you elaborate? I am assuming that the increment will happen if I can save successfully, otherwise I will decrement. Where is the problem?

Comment: @Epsi95 There is endless information on the web why global variables are a bad idea, look it up.

Answer (score 0):

You can get number of files in the current directory and add 1 to it.
Here is code to get number of files in current dir

```
import os, os.path

print(len([name for name in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(name)]))
```

Comment: This is a very bad idea if there are thousands of files.

Comment: Considering he has a special directory to store output files - its an good ideas.